# WebRTC видеосвязь

Tags: javascript

Не получается создать видеосвязь, ссылку получает, но не отображает:

HTML:

```
<video id="localVideo" width="360" height="240" autoplay="true"></video>
<video id="remoteVideo" width="360" height="240" autoplay="true"></video>
```

JS:

```
var peerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.msRTCPeerConnection;
var sessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription || window.msRTCSessionDescription;
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var onePeer = new peerConnection();
var twoPeer = new peerConnection();

onePeer.onaddstream = function(obj) {
    document.getElementById("localVideo").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(obj.stream);
}

function error(err) {
    //Error
}

function initialize() {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {video:true}, 
        function(stream){
            onePeer.onaddstream({stream: stream});
            onePeer.addStream(stream);

            onePeer.createOffer(function(offer) {
                    onePeer.setLocalDescription(new sessionDescription(offer), function() {
                                        // Пытаюсь принять:
                    remote(offer);
                    }, error);
            }, error);
        }, 
        function(error){console.log("Failed to get access to local media. Error code was " + error.code);}
    );
}

//Получает ссылку - но не отображает, почему?
twoPeer.onaddstream = function(obj) {document.getElementById("remoteVideo").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(obj.stream);};

function remote(obj) {
    twoPeer.setRemoteDescription(new sessionDescription(obj), function() {
            twoPeer.createAnswer(function(answer) {
                twoPeer.setLocalDescription(new sessionDescription(answer), function() {
                    // ANSWER
                }, error);
            }, error);
    }, error);
}

setTimeout(initialize, 1);
```

Консоль выдает ошибку:

> ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details

Comment: Вы сделали то, что написано в сообщении об ошибке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обмен SDP не достаточен для установки соединения, надо реализовать обмен ICE кандидатами https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/WebRTC_basics

Пример открытия видео потока с использование библиотеки Easy-API https://plnkr.co/edit/4sVzu7?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <script src="//server1.easy-api.com/easy-api.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      div { width: 320px; height: 240px; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='media'></div>
    <div id='player'></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      Easy.init({siteId: 'W4400388548'},function(response) {
        Easy.media('media',{level:0}).flow().start(function(response){
          Easy.player('player').play(response.streamId);
        });
      });
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```